# Flutter how to integrate Admob?

Tags: android, flutter, admob, firebase-admob

I followed [this](https://medium.com/@sravanyakatta6/showing-ads-in-flutter-app-f9f1b72eec51) tutorial on integrating AdMob in Flutter, but when I try to run my app this is the only output I get in the debug console .. And the app does not launch. I also set the AddMob app id in the AndroidManifest.xml like in the official [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_admob#-readme-tab-) on the firebase_admob package.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√ Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
```

[image]

This is the last feature I need to implement before I can publish my app, really frustrated now ..

Comment: can you try 0.5.5 version

Comment: same behaviour :/

Comment: When I remove: implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.1.0' from build.gradle(app) it works

Comment: I have just written a detailed blog post on how to set up AdMob ads in Flutter apps.
[check it out.](https://yassinebenkhay.com/how-to-integrate-admob-ads-in-flutter/)